# Need to check class exist in multiple div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, meteor-blaze

There are multiple divs of step_input as class and inside those divs may or may not consists spans with same class. I need to check whether a particular span exist in any of the div with class as step_input. Then change the color of spans with same class which exists in selectable-tags class.I had to use javascript only

Here in the fiddle span1 exists in the step_input class. So its color in selectable-tags needs to be changed.
Here's a fiddle [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/akhilsahu/qutx98qo/)

```js
  var parentz = document.querySelectorAll('step_input');

  for(i=0;i<document.querySelectorAll('.selectable-tags > span').length;i++)
   {
      tagclassName='ing-tag_'+i; 
       for(k=0;k<parentz.length;k++)
       if ( parentz[k].querySelector("."+tagclassName) !== null) {
       document.querySelector('.selectable-tags > tagclassName').style.backgroundColor="#fafafa";
    }  
   
   }
```

```html
<div  class="selectable-tags"  >
   <span  data-class="label" style="background-color: red;" class="ing-tag_0"> Span1 </span> &nbsp;
   <span style="background-color: red;"  data-class="label" class="ing-tag_1"> wqq </span> &nbsp;
</div>
<div  class="selectable-tags"  >
   <span style="background-color: red" data-class="label" class="ing-tag_0"> Span1 </span> &nbsp;
   <span style="background-color: red;"  data-class="label" class="ing-tag_1"> wqq </span> &nbsp;
</div>
<div   id="step_input_0" name="step"   class="recipe-create-text_box_rectangle stepbox step_input" contenteditable="true"> This does not contains anything 
</div>
<div value="" id="step_input_1" name="step" placeholder="Tell us about step 2" class="recipe-create-text_box_rectangle stepbox step_input" contenteditable="true"> <span  style="background-color: red;" data-class="label" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> Span1 </span>Thw color of span 1 in selectable tags needs to change&nbsp;</div>
```

Edit: When a span with is detected in the step_input. Its corresponding one in .selectable_tags class 's color changes. Like here Span1 with class 'ing-tag_1' is in step_input class. Now the color of Span1 in the div with class selectable_tags 's color needs to be change. Please suggest a better way to do this if there's one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change color each selectable tag one by by one. The following would check and color the tag which are present in the step_input

```js
 var parentz = document.querySelectorAll('.step_input');
console.log(parentz);
for(i=0;i<document.querySelectorAll('.selectable-tags > span').length;i++){console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.selectable-tags > span'));
          tagclassName='ing-tag_'+i; 
           for(k=0;k<parentz.length;k++){
      if ( parentz[k].querySelector("."+tagclassName) !== null) {  
           colorthem= document.querySelectorAll('.selectable-tags > .'+tagclassName)    ;console.log(colorthem);
           for(l=0;l<colorthem.length;l++)
                                                                 {console.log(colorthem[l]);
             colorthem[l].style.backgroundColor="red";
       }  }
       
    }}
```

```html
<div  class="selectable-tags"  >
   <span  data-class="label" style="background-color: red;" class="ing-tag_0"> Span1 </span> &nbsp;
   <span style="background-color: red;"  data-class="label" class="ing-tag_1"> wqq </span> &nbsp;
</div>
<div  class="selectable-tags"  >
   <span style="background-color: red" data-class="label" class="ing-tag_0"> Span1 </span> &nbsp;
   <span style="background-color: red;"  data-class="label" class="ing-tag_1"> wqq </span> &nbsp;
</div>
<div   id="step_input_0" name="step"   class="recipe-create-text_box_rectangle stepbox step_input" contenteditable="true"> This does not contains anything 
</div>
<div value="" id="step_input_1" name="step" placeholder="Tell us about step 2" class="recipe-create-text_box_rectangle stepbox step_input" contenteditable="true"> <span  style="background-color: red;" data-class="label" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> Span1 </span>Thw color of span 1 in selectable tags needs to change&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Is it this what you need?

```js
var parentz = document.querySelectorAll('.step_input');
var selectable = document.querySelectorAll('.selectable-tags');


  for(j=0; j < selectable.length; j++){
    var current = selectable[j];
    var spans = current.querySelectorAll('.selectable-tags > span');
    
    for(i=0; i < spans.length; i++){ 

      tagclassName='ing-tag_'+i; 
      for(k=0; k < parentz.length; k++){
      
        if (parentz[k].querySelector("."+tagclassName)) {
           selectable[j].querySelector('.' +tagclassName).style.backgroundColor="#fafafa";
        }  
        
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div  class="selectable-tags"  >
   <span  data-class="label 11" style="background-color: red;" class="ing-tag_0"> Span1 </span> &nbsp;
   <span style="background-color: red;"  data-class="label" class="ing-tag_1"> wqq </span> &nbsp;
</div>
<div  class="selectable-tags"  >
   <span style="background-color: red" data-class="label" class="ing-tag_0"> Span1 </span> &nbsp;
   <span style="background-color: red;"  data-class="label" class="ing-tag_1"> wqq </span> &nbsp;
</div>
<div   id="step_input_0" name="step"   class="recipe-create-text_box_rectangle stepbox step_input" contenteditable="true"> This does not contains anything 
</div>
<div value="" id="step_input_1" name="step" placeholder="Tell us about step 2" class="recipe-create-text_box_rectangle stepbox step_input" contenteditable="true"> 

<span  style="background-color: red;" data-class="label" class="ing-tag_0" contenteditable="false"> Span1 </span>

Thw color of span 1 in selectable tags needs to change&nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: This does not changes color of Span1 in all divs selectable-tags. This works fine only on the first one but not on second Span1.

Answer (score -1):

I did not get what you're asking for, but as far as I can see, the selector `.selectable-tags > span` should work fine for direct children. Which you did already.

EDIT:
First of all,

`var parentz = document.querySelectorAll('step_input');`

this line checks for tags with the name `step_input` which does not exist in your HTML, there are IDs with `step_input_0` for that you'll need to prepare an array of ID by running a loop. Otherwise you can use `document.getElementsByName("step")`

Again,
You just have to traverse the DOM, to access the span inside `div`s with name `name` it would look something like:

```
const divsWithStep = document.getElementsByName("step");
divsWithStep.forEach((div)=>{
  div.querySelector('span').style.backgroundColor="#fafafa";
})
```

Again, I think you should look up on DOM traversing, let me know.

Comment: This isn't an answer, this should be a comment.

Comment: wanted to comment, but don't have 50 reputation yet.

Comment: @HrishikeshBarman  The color of corresponding  span in selectable tags class needs to be change not itself step_input. Please read the code properly `class="recipe-create-text_box_rectangle stepbox step_input"`